# ST_INTERSECTS query gets ignored

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I've got a list of LATLNG-coordinates and a table ready with a location-column called 'location'. I want to only show the results within the radius of 500 meter.

So this is the code with the latlng of one of the items in the list:

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
  select: 'location',
  from: '1881TVJgnC7HbzM0ZCsBfg72MOlpini6F79a9Vko',
  where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(location, CIRCLE(LATLNG(51.728669, 5.254821), 500))'
}});
layer.setMap(map);
```

Does anyone have an idea why the 'where'-part is getting ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that in your [table 1881TVJgnC7HbzM0ZCsBfg72MOlpini6F79a9Vko](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1881TVJgnC7HbzM0ZCsBfg72MOlpini6F79a9Vko#rows%3aid=1) there is no column named `location`, only `lat` and `lon`. In these cases, Google Fusion Tables creates a combined column for those two, where `lat` can be used as a placeholder for both:

```js
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: 'lat',
        from: '1881TVJgnC7HbzM0ZCsBfg72MOlpini6F79a9Vko',
        where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(lat, CIRCLE(LATLNG(51.728669, 5.254821), 500))'
    }
});
layer.setMap(map);
```

I created a [running example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/M2LbG/). There you can play around and change the radius using the slider to see how the result changes.

Comment: Thanks Odi, Worked perfect!